# disable submit button in directive

Tags: angularjs

I simply want to add the class `disable` when `form.$valid` is `false`. The first submit button (not directive) obiouvsly works, but I don't know how to make visible the form state inside the directive. I cannot hardcode the form name in directive, it should be reusable in several forms..

```
<form id="tA" name="form" ng-controller="ctrl" ng-submit="form.$valid && save()" novalidate>

    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="title" name="name" ng-model="model.name" required ng-required="true">

    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{'disabled' : !form.$valid}" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>

<button-raised disabled="!form.$valid">directive Submit</button-raised>
```

---

```
app.directive('buttonRaised', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<button class="mdl-button" ng-class="ngClass" ng-transclude></button>',
    scope: {
        ngModel: '='
    },
    transclude: true,
    link: function($scope, el, $attrs,formCtrl) {
        console.log(formCtrl)
        $scope.ngClass = {
           // 'disabled': $scope.$parent.formCtrl.$valid,
        };
    }
};
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way to do this is to pass your boolean as a parameter of your directive :

```
app.directive('buttonRaised', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<button class="mdl-button" ng-disabled="disabled" ng-class="ngClass" ng-transclude></button>',
    scope: {
        ngModel: '=',
        disabled: '='
    },
    transclude: true,
    link: function($scope, el, $attrs,formCtrl) {
        console.log(formCtrl)
        $scope.ngClass = {
           // 'disabled': $scope.$parent.formCtrl.$valid,
        };
    }
};
```

});

Comment: And I guess it's the fastest way :)

Comment: You only pass the value to your directive. You don't need treatment or call other thing, you only want to disable the button ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can change the directive and html as per this working [this](http://jsfiddle.net/vvfnN/2/)

The directive

```
app.directive('buttonRaised', function() {
     return {
         restrict: 'E',
         template: '<button class="mdl-button" ng-class="{\'disabled\': disableButton}" ng-transclude></button>',
         scope: {
            disableButton: '='
          },
          transclude: true,
          link: function($scope, el, $attrs,formCtrl) {
               console.log(formCtrl)

           }
        };
      });
```

The html

```
 <form id="tA" name="form" ng-controller="ctrl" ng-submit="form.$valid && save()" novalidate>

  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="title" name="name" ng-model="model.name" required ng-required="true">

  <button class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{'disabled' : !form.$valid}" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>


  // directive taking parameter disable-button
  <button-raised disable-button="!form.$valid">directive Submit</button-raised>
```